# recv function gets stuck even if send is successfull

Tags: c, sockets, dns

I am trying to send dns query to a dns server.
even though my send function is working but the recv function does not return any this.
it does not give any error either.
it gets stuck after the "Receiving answer...." line

struct sockaddr_in dest;

```
dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest.sin_port = htons(53);
dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("208.67.222.222"); //dns servers

int s;
s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP);


int query_size=sizeof(struct DNS_HEADER) + (strlen((const char*)domain)+1) + 4;
printf("\n\nquery size - %d",query_size);

int cs=connect(s,(struct sockaddr*)&dest,sizeof(dest));
if(cs==0)
{
    printf("\n\nconnect success\n\n");
}
printf("\nSending Packet...");
if( send(s,(char*)buf,query_size,0) < 0)
{
    perror("sendto failed");
}
printf("Done");

//Receive the answer
i = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
printf("\nReceiving answer...");

if(recv(s,(char*)buf , 65536,0) < 0)
{
    perror("recvfrom failed");
}
printf("Done");
```

Comment: What is the other end doing? Are you sure it's sending a response? Is the request you send correct for what you're doing?

Comment: And why are you connecting to an UDP service? UDP is an *unconnected* protocol. For UDP you usually bind the local socket to a local address, and then use `sendto` and `recvfrom` to send and receive packets.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You can use `connect()` with a UDP socket; it sets the default address used when sending data via `write()`, `send()`, etc. syscalls that don't explicitly include an address. It also restricts the socket to only receiving datagrams from that address.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Re "*And why are you connecting to an UDP service? UDP is an unconnected protocol.*", Nonetheless, `connect` has well-defined semantics for datagram protocols like UDP. It sets the default address for sending (allowing `send` to be used), and it limits from which address packets will be received.

Comment: I am using UDP because the socket is connected to a DNS server

Comment: What is content of the `buf`? Perhaps DNS server does not respond because the DNS query is not valid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "And why are you connecting to an UDP service?" Because DNS is a protocol running on both (either of) UDP and TCP.

Comment: What happens if you try the same query from same host with another tool/client like `dig`? In your case, do you see the reply coming if you look at the network level (with `wireshark` or `tcpdump`)? You need to show the content of your "buf", how do you generate it? Did you read RFC 1034 and 1035 multiple times to clearly understand how DNS packets are formed? For local developments you should install a local recursive DNS server open only to your host and debug your program towards it, it would be far simpler to look at what is happening on both ends that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. the problem was in my dns header structure. I declared it like this

```
struct DNS_HEADER
{
    unsigned short id;

    unsigned char qr :1;
    unsigned char opcode :4;
    unsigned char aa :1;
    unsigned char tc: 1;
    unsigned char rd: 1;
    unsigned char ra: 1;
    unsigned char z :3;
    unsigned char rcode :4;

    unsigned short qdcount;

    unsigned short ancount;

    unsigned short nscount;

    unsigned short arcount;

};
```

the problem here is that.the flag byets does not get converted in network byte order. when I rearranged the structure variables it workd.

```
struct DNS_HEADER
{
    unsigned short id; // identification number

    unsigned char rd :1; // recursion desired
    unsigned char tc :1; // truncated message
    unsigned char aa :1; // authoritive answer
    unsigned char opcode :4; // purpose of message
    unsigned char qr :1; // query/response flag

    unsigned char rcode :4; // response code
    unsigned char cd :1; // checking disabled
    unsigned char ad :1; // authenticated data
    unsigned char z :1; // its z! reserved
    unsigned char ra :1; // recursion available

    unsigned short qdcount; // number of question entries
    unsigned short ancount; // number of answer entries
    unsigned short nscount; // number of authority entries
    unsigned short arcount; // number of resource entries
};
```